# Are drivers for 3DConnexion devices included in FreeCAD/ParaVIEW?

Tags: 12.04, cad

Are drivers for the different 3D CAD packages (FreeCAD, ParaVIEW, etc) included in Ubuntu for 3DConnexion devices?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the "3DConnexion devices"? Maybe provide a link to a product page? And what kind of devices are this? Printers? And what have you tried? What do logs say when you connect such a device to your PC?

Answer (score 1):

3DConnexion devices are known as 3D mice or spaceball (former name). The most widely used is the SpaceNavigator. 3DConnexion.com is the website.

There is an open source driver named spacenav. It's available through the libspnav0 package. FreeCAD supports it, but the package available in Ubuntu repositories has not been built with it. To use it, I suggest you add one of the FreeCAD PPA to update your FreeCAD to a version which supports those devices.

I don't know of other CAD apps supporting spacenav.